# MvvmCross Could not find a Setup class for application

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have an Xamarin Forms Android Application with MvvmCross and I see several of these exceptions in my insights.

When the app starts from scratch everything works fine. As far as I can tell this error happens, wenn the app is moved to hibernation and is started again.

I have a SplashScreenActivity which defines the Setup class as follows:

```
MvxFormsSplashScreenActivity<ApplicationSetup, CoreApp, App>
```

In case it helps, the Project is open source and the code lies here: https://github.com/MoneyFox/MoneyFox

How can I fix that?

Error:

```
Package: com.applysolutions.moneyfox
Version Code: 2019099001
Version Name: 5.1.2019099.001
Android: 9
Android Build: PQ2A.190405.003
Manufacturer: Google
Model: Pixel 3
CrashReporter Key: c69e70df-a610-4112-be05-e3869f130474
Date: undefined

Xamarin Exception Stack:
MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to create setup instance
  at MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetupSingleton.CreateSetup () [0x00017] in <5379a95ac98a4680b7bb47f5b716a158>:0
  at MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable[TMvxSetupSingleton] () [0x00045] in <5379a95ac98a4680b7bb47f5b716a158>:0
  at MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Core.MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable (Android.Content.Context applicationContext) [0x00000] in <5379a95ac98a4680b7bb47f5b716a158>:0
  at MvvmCross.Forms.Platforms.Android.Views.MvxFormsAppCompatActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00006] in <4ea0c9ab37e14fd8aa188ddf8fa8736e>:0
  at MoneyFox.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00052] in <2cfc40e7b7be4d839b84f168044b373f>:0
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in <8ac02975c09144d5ae9c10aecc6be0c2>:0
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.9(intptr,intptr,intptr)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: Could not find a Setup class for application
    at MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetupExtensions.CreateSetup[TSetup] () [0x00019] in <5379a95ac98a4680b7bb47f5b716a158>:0
    at MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetup.Instance () [0x00015] in <5379a95ac98a4680b7bb47f5b716a158>:0
    at MvvmCross.Core.MvxSetupSingleton.CreateSetup () [0x00000] in <5379a95ac98a4680b7bb47f5b716a158>:0

Thread 2:
0   dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(VMStack.java:-2)
1   java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1538)
2   java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1588)
3   com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.Crashes.saveUncaughtException(Crashes.java:943)
4   com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.WrapperSdkExceptionManager.saveWrapperException(WrapperSdkExceptionManager.java:50)
5   md5a0013181b845adff0c8407b475a96272.MainActivity.n_onCreate(MainActivity.java:-2)
6   md5a0013181b845adff0c8407b475a96272.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
7   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
8   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
9   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
10  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
11  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
12  android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
13  android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
14  android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
15  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
16  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
17  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
18  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
19  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
20  com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
21  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Thread 6698:
0   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-2)
1   java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:178)
2   java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
3   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Thread 6699:
0   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-2)
1   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:422)
2   java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:188)
3   java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:209)
4   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:232)
5   java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
6   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Thread 6700:
0   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:-2)
1   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:373)
2   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:314)
3   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepFor(Daemons.java:342)
4   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForFinalization(Daemons.java:364)
5   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:281)
6   java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
7   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Thread 6707:
0   android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java:-2)
1   android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
2   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
3   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)

Thread 6709:
0   android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java:-2)
1   android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
2   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
3   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)

Thread 6710:
0   android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java:-2)
1   android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
2   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
3   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

EDIT: I tried if it behaves differently, when I deactivate linking. But that didn't have an effect.